# What RAID controller for HP Proliant DL160 G6 for 4x3TB SATA HDDs

Tags: raid, hp-proliant

I have HP Proliant DL160 G6 server and four 3TB SATA hard drives. Onboard controller is supporting 2TB max. I bought P410 smart array convinced it supports 3TB SATA drives, but it doesn't. I don't remember what I was looking at.

Anyway, I need to find right controller eventually. After my research I found P812, which according to quickspec pdf supports up to 4TB hot plug SATA and 3TB non hot plug SATA drives.

Could you please confirm this controller:

- will fit physically and electrically in DL160 G6
- support 3TB SATA drives.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update your firmware on the system and RAID controller. 3TB disks should be fine.

Comment: Which one? Integrated B110i controller? Or P410?

Comment: Both will work.